# Add filled circle for 0% observations

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to add coloured circles in the gaps where there are no species present to clearly show what species are missing from the group.

```
library(ggplot2)

Species <- c("Anoplolepis sp1", "Anoplolepis custodiens", "Camponotus sp1", "Camponotus fulvopilosis", "Pheidole megacephala", "Anoplolepis custodiens", "Camponotus sp1", "Camponotus fulvopilosis", "Anoplolepis sp1", "Anoplolepis custodiens", "Camponotus sp1", "Camponotus fulvopilosis")
Site <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C")
Portion <- c(5/38*100, 23/38*100, 8/38*100, 2/38*100, 16/41*100, 7/41*100, 18/41*100, 0/41*100, 0/18*100, 3/18*100, 10/18*100, 5/18*100)

df <- data.frame(Site, Species, Portion)
colnames(df) <- c("SITE", "SPECIES", "PORTION")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = SPECIES, y = PORTION, fill = SPECIES)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")  +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 65), breaks = 10*c(0:6)) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(~SITE, switch = "x", scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5, size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "SPECIES",
                    values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73"))+
  ylab("Portion of total ant found at site") +
  xlab("Site") +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_line("lightgray"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.title=element_text(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "italic"),
        text = element_text(size=12))
```

The graph looks like this at the end:
[image: Graph showing the portion for each species collected at each site]

I would like to add in filled circles for the 0 observations to show what species are missing from each site that wasn't collected there, but was expected

I would like to do it without adding each species name on the x-axis as this just gets really messy. My dataset has over 50 sites and about 13 species

Comment: I'm getting the error `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 5 needed but only 4 provided.`, also a warning that ``panel.margin` is deprecated. Please use `panel.spacing` property instead `

Answer (score 2):

For example, adding

```
# ... your plotting chain + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")) + # dupe fill cols
  geom_point(
    aes(size=ifelse(is.na(PORTION),1,NA),color=SPECIES), 
    tidyr::complete(df, SITE, SPECIES), 
    y=1, 
    show.legend = F)
```

should give you something like

[image]

Similarly, this would also include zero values:

```
  geom_point(
    aes(size=ifelse(is.na(PORTION) | PORTION==0,1,NA),color=SPECIES), 
    tidyr::complete(df, SITE, SPECIES), 
    y=1, 
    show.legend = F)
```

[image]

Comment: I keep on getting the following error if i try the code:  Error in UseMethod("complete_") : 
  no applicable method for 'complete_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @LudwigEksteen Probably because you have your data not in a data frame called `df`...

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Any way of removing the species from the graphs that weren't expected at the site?

Comment: Just remove the tidyr::complete(df, SITE, SPECIES)

Comment: Yes, that would be `geom_point(
    aes(size=ifelse(PORTION==0,1,NA),color=SPECIES), 
    y=1, 
    show.legend = F)`